# Retroactively update a collection of MongoDB docs with a create date field

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, document

I am trying to add a field to a collection of documents. All I want to do is update each document with a field called create_date with the timestamp they were created on as the value. I know you can get the timestamp from the ObjectId using _id.getTimestamp() but I'm looking for some mongodb shell command that I could use to do this easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Question. The following code worked for me in 3.2:

```
db.members.update({},{$set : {"createdAt":{
        "$date": "2017-01-01T09:19:38.116Z"
    }}},false,true)
```

In the above example last 2 fields false, true specifies the upsert and multi flags.

Upsert: If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

Multi: If set to true, updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria. If set to false, updates one document.

In 3.2 you could use the following command as well:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{$set : {"createdAt": new Date("2017-01-01T09:19:38.116Z")}})
```